# extract word if only certain length criteria is met

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract a word following a keyword only if the word is < 20 characters long...

```
my_regex = re.compile(r'(keyword)\s*(\S{0,20}$))
```

for example:

```
keyword anbc123
```

will extract `keyword` and `anbc123`.

however below should not give any result

```
keyword anbc123nmnmnmnmnmnmnmnmnmnmn
```

this works...

But, below should work too since word following keyword is less than 20 characters long..how do I fix the regex ? I understand $ is for end of string....

```
keyword abnc 1234
```

expected result: `keyword abnc`

Comment: Try `(keyword)\s*(\S{1,20})(?!\S)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uWx2Mm/1).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `\b` in place of `$`, `\b` matches a "word boundary", meaning the beginning or end of a word. In this case it will match the end of the word or end of the string

```
(keyword)\s*(\S{0,20})\b
```